# Check that $x$ can be taken to be an extremal point of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, extreme-value-analysis

> Let $T : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be a linear map. Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$
>   be a convex, closed and bounded set. We know that there exists $x_0 \in A$ such that $\sup T(x) = T(x_0)$.
>   Check that $\tilde x_0$ can be taken to be an extremal point of $A$.

I feel like I need to use the extremal point definition but do not know how to incorporate it.

**Def.:** $P$ is an extreme point of $S$ if there do not exist points $Q_1$, $Q_2$ of $S$ with distinct $Q_1$, $Q_2$ such that $P$ can be written in the form $P = t Q_1 + (1 - t)Q_2$ with $0 < t < 1$.

Comment: Can you state the definition you are working with?

Comment: yes i added it!

Comment: I think your statement "with unique $Q_1,Q_2$" should be "with distinct $Q_1,Q_2$."

Answer (score 1):

It is well know that $A$ is the convex hull of the set of extreme points. Hence $x_0= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} t_ix_i$ with $t_i >0,\sum t_i=1$ and each $x_i$ an extreme point of $A$. If $T$ does not attain its maximum value at any of the $x_i$'s then $T(x_0)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} t_i T(x_i)$ which is strictly less than the maximum value of $T$ on $A$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Reference: Krein Milman Theorem and the third theorem following it in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Comment: is there a way to show extreme point without Krein Milman's Theorem?

Comment: To answer this question you have to know that $A$ has an extreme point. I am not aware of any way of proving existence of extreme points avoiding Krein -Milman.

Comment: Here is something you can think about. Suppose $A$ is a compact convex set in $\mathbb R^{n}$. You do not know how this set looks like geometrically. Can you think of proving that it has at least one extreme point without Krein Milman Theorem?

Comment: in your first answer, what is the contradiction?

Comment: If $M$ is the maximum value then $T(x_i) <M$ for all $i$ implies $T(x_0) <M$. But $x_0$ is, by definition, a point with $T(x_0)=M$.